# Git: show branches that have different commits compared to master?

Tags: git, branch, git-log

I have a repo that got quite large with several branches. I rebased some important stuff and merged branches that I might need in future - so far, so good. However, I have the feeling that I am missing some old branch that never got merged into `master`. Due to the size of the repo and amount of commits it is hard to scroll through and identify the problem with `gitg` or `git log --online --decorate --graph --all`.

Is it possible to somehow reduce the graph to just the most recent commit for every branch and preferably only stuff that is different to `master`?

Comment: Along with A DOG (all decorate oneline graph), try adding `--simplify-by-decoration`, which omits commits that *don't* have the decorations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You specify the refspec `^master` (not reachable from master). That should get you going

```
git log --all ^master
```